# VB.Net recursion dead end

Tags: vb.net, recursion, directory

I have some code that should take a starting directory and loop through that and all subdirectories but instead it's getting to the last subdirectory in the first branch it goes down and exits out.  I know there are a bunch of these, but I can't figure out how to get past the last subdirectory.  I was hoping someone could point out how to continue on through the next directory branch.  (It's just checking for files older than 1 hour and emailing me and that part works fine, it just doesn't look everywhere).

```
    Sub Main()
    Dim dirList As New String("C:\Users\Test\SampleDir")
    Dim lOldNames = New List(Of String)()

    ListFiles(dirList, lOldNames)

    If lOldNames.Count > 0 Then
        sendMail(lOldNames)
    End If

    End Sub


Public Function ListFiles(ByVal sdirList As String, ByVal lOldNames As List(Of String))
    Dim dirList As New DirectoryInfo(sdirList)
    Dim fiFileList As FileInfo() = dirList.GetFiles()
    Dim fiName As FileInfo
    Dim bEmpty As Boolean = False

    bEmpty = IsDirectoryEmpty(dirList.ToString)
    If bEmpty = False Then
        For Each fiName In fiFileList
            If fiName.CreationTime.AddHours(1) < DateTime.Now Then
                lOldNames.Add(fiName.FullName)
            End If
        Next fiName
    End If

    Dim subDirs() As DirectoryInfo = dirList.GetDirectories()
    For Each subdir As DirectoryInfo In subDirs
        ListFiles(subdir.FullName, lOldNames)
    Next subdir

    Return lOldNames

End Function


    'Function to test if directory is empty
Public Function IsDirectoryEmpty(ByVal path As String) As Boolean
    Return Not (Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(path).Any())
End Function
```

Fixed and shortened the function call per Steve's comment below:

```
Public Function ListFiles(ByVal sdirList As String, ByVal lOldNames As List(Of String))
    Dim dirList As New DirectoryInfo(sdirList)
    Dim fiFileList As FileInfo() = dirList.GetFiles()
    Dim dirs As String() = Directory.GetFiles(sdirList, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)

    For Each sfile As String In dirs
        If Not sfile.Contains("Software") AndAlso Not sfile.Contains("Outbound") AndAlso Not sfile.Contains("RECYCLE.BIN") AndAlso Not sfile.Contains("System Volume") Then

            Dim fiName As New FileInfo(sfile)

            If fiName.CreationTime.AddHours(1) < DateTime.Now Then
                lOldNames.Add(fiName.FullName)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Return lOldNames

End Function
```

Comment: I couldn't run IsDirectoryEmpty on my environment so I removed it and everything is working fine for me. Maybe your files are less dans an hour. The code only gets everything older than 1 hour.

Comment: I commented out the IsDirectoryEmpty as well and it still hits the End Function before it searches all the directories.  I have my root dir that has files in it and 2 subdirs, and each of them have 2 subdirs as well.  The program gets to the root/subdir/subdir and exits while I want it to go through however many there are at any level below the root.

Comment: It is pretty obvious that you posted fake code.  We can't see the Try/Catch that actually makes it stop recursing the directories.

Comment: No it's not.  If I'm getting the directory name from DirectoryInfo, why would I need a try/catch block?  In case someone deletes a folder in the millisecond between when the code gets the list and when it checks the files?  This is to check for files that have been sitting on an FTP server and haven't been picked up for some reason, the folders won't ever be deleted so I didn't bother to test if the folder was there, since it always will be.  The code gets to the last subdirectory, and gets to the line: Next subdir and then moves to: Return lOldNames and then: End Function.

Comment: You could fix your problem and make this code a lot smaller if you knew the GetFiles() takes an optional parameter that traverses all subdirectories for you. But I'm not telling.

Comment: BTW @Dave, if you don't tag the person you are talking to, they don't always get notified that you are talking to them, unless they are the one that originally submitted the question/answer.

Comment: @Steve I forgot about the tagging.  I'll take a look at GetFiles() and re-write the module and see how it works.  Thanks (maybe) :)